# Magento 1.9.x installation error

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, zend-framework

1. I tried installation with browser as follows

   a. url/install.php

   b. but at after db setting in installation wizard, browser gives 504 Gateway error
2. So I tried with terminal and tried following command,

   php -f install.php -- --license_agreement_accepted yes --locale en_US --timezone "America/Los_Angeles" --default_currency USD --db_host localhost --db_name magento1x --db_user user --db_pass 123123 --db_prefix mage_ --url "http://base_url/" --use_rewrites yes --use_secure yes --secure_base_url "http://base_url/" --use_secure_admin yes --admin_lastname Lname --admin_firstname Fname --admin_email "abc@xyz.com" --admin_username username --admin_password 123123123

   but I am getting following exception,

   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: it seems like issue is with your database connection. Please re-check and try again.

Comment: @sumit the database connection is proper, I tried with normal PHP mysqli()

Comment: At least I need a remedy for 504 gateway error (in which conf file I need to do changes and which are the changes), so I can proceed with browser

Comment: check local.xml file of your installation.